# First variation of induced metric on a hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Reference: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511)

At [page 15](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511), we could see that the first variation of the induced metric on a hypersurface $\Sigma(t)$ computed as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{\Sigma(t)} = v(t) g_{\Sigma(t)},  \forall t \in (-\delta,\delta) \tag{1}$$

since $\Sigma(t)$ is umbilic and $H_t$ is constant, where $v$ is a real function.

And then for all $t \in (-\delta, \delta)$

$$g_{\Sigma(t)}  = e^{\int^t_0 v(s) ds} = u(t)^2 g_{\mathbb S^2} \tag{2}$$

where $u(t)=a e^{\int^t_0 v(s) ds}$ with $a^2=|\Sigma|/4\pi \in (0,1)$.

**Question:**

Where do I start to get the expression (1) and (2)? I don't have any clue at all. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the notion of an umbilic hypersurface, but this might work: compute for a smooth normal variation with speed $\sigma(t)$ that $\partial_t g_{ij} = \sigma(t)h_{ij}$ just by working in local coordinates, using the chain rule, and the Weingarten relation ($\partial_i\nu^\alpha = h^k_i\partial_k\Sigma^\alpha$). Thus, $\partial_tg=\sigma(t)h$... now if it is true that $h=\lambda g$ for some smooth function $\lambda$ for an umbilic surface with constant mean curvature you are done! (but I'm sure at all about that last statement)

Comment: @yousufsoliman ok thanks I'll try